# SQL Server Duplicated ID IN JOIN Table Generates incorrect Sum(Cases)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query which is giving me the incorrect sum.It is duplicating the sum of the Cases when join Table Runlog with Table Palletitem. I have tried several different queries, also tried getting the sum in a subquery, but I can't get rid of that duplicate. my current query is as good as could get. Thanks for the help

Expected Result

```sql
RunID   Cases    LotNumber
1749    416.00   B703, B705
```

Current Result with Current Code

```sql
RunID   Cases    LotNumber
1749    520.00   B703, B705
```

Current Code

```sql
SELECT distinct RunLog.RunID,
  Sum(RunLog.casecount) AS Cases,
    stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(lot.lotnumber AS varchar(20))
                           FROM         PalletItem t2 inner JOIN
                                              Lot ON Lot.ID = t2.Lotid
                                             AND t2.RunID = RunLog.RunID
                           WHERE      
                            t2.datepalletized>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
                             and t2.datepalletized<='2019-06-10 20:00:00'
                             group by lot.lotnumber
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [LotNumber]

FROM RunLog
   INNER JOIN Lot on Lot.runid=RunLog.runid
   INNER JOIN PalletItem ON PalletItem.LotNumber = Lot.ID 
   AND palletitem.palletid=runlog.palletid 
   WHERE RunLog.ActionDate>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
   AND RunLog.ActionDate<='2019-06-10 19:02:00'
GROUP BY RunLog.RunID
```

SAMPLE DATA BELOW

Tables

```sql
PalletItem
                     --------------
PalletID    Lotid       DatePalletized       RunID
2004109     14657       2019-06-10 16:53:00  1749      
2004110     14657       2019-06-10 17:47:00  1749      
2004110     14659       2019-06-10 17:47:00  1749      
2004111     14659       2019-06-10 17:48:00  1749      
2004112     14659       2019-06-10 19:01:00  1749    
                      ---------------


Runlog
                     ---------------
RunID   PalletID    casecount   ActionDate
1749    2004109     104.00      2019-06-10 16:52:52.000
1749    2004110     104.00      2019-06-10 17:46:58.000
1749    2004111     104.00      2019-06-10 17:47:36.000
1749    2004112     104.00      2019-06-10 19:00:38.000
                     -----------------

Lot 
     ------
ID      LotNumber   runid
14657   B703        1749
14659   B705        1749
    --------
```

Comment: Since you are using SQL Server, why did you tag MySQL?

Comment: stackoverflow suggested on the suggestion tag, I was not going to put it, but tried to follow guidelines to get better answer.

Comment: Looks like you can safely drop all but `RunLog` table from the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two `INNER JOIN` introduce many-to-many connection. That's why you have duplicates. What's more you are not using columns from those tables in your `select`. You don't need `distinct`, the table has already `group by`.

```
SELECT RunLog.RunID,
  Sum(RunLog.casecount) AS Cases,
    stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(lot.lotnumber AS varchar(20))
                           FROM         PalletItem t2 inner JOIN
                                              Lot ON Lot.ID = t2.Lotid
                                             AND t2.RunID = RunLog.RunID
                           WHERE      
                            t2.datepalletized>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
                             and t2.datepalletized<='2019-06-10 20:00:00'
                             group by lot.lotnumber
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [LotNumber]

FROM RunLog
   --INNER JOIN Lot on Lot.runid=RunLog.runid
   --INNER JOIN PalletItem ON PalletItem.Lotid = Lot.ID 
   --AND palletitem.palletid=runlog.palletid 
   WHERE RunLog.ActionDate>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
   AND RunLog.ActionDate<='2019-06-10 19:02:00'
GROUP BY RunLog.RunID
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
SELECT Sum(RunLog.casecount) AS Cases, count(*) rows
FROM RunLog
--   INNER JOIN Lot on Lot.runid=RunLog.runid
--   INNER JOIN PalletItem ON PalletItem.LotNumber = Lot.ID 
--   AND palletitem.palletid=runlog.palletid 
   WHERE RunLog.ActionDate>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
   AND RunLog.ActionDate<='2019-06-10 19:02:00'
--GROUP BY RunLog.RunID
```

then

```
SELECT Sum(RunLog.casecount) AS Cases, count(*) rows
FROM RunLog
     INNER JOIN Lot on Lot.runid=RunLog.runid
--   INNER JOIN PalletItem ON PalletItem.LotNumber = Lot.ID 
--   AND palletitem.palletid=runlog.palletid 
   WHERE RunLog.ActionDate>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
   AND RunLog.ActionDate<='2019-06-10 19:02:00'
--GROUP BY RunLog.RunID
```

then

```
SELECT Sum(RunLog.casecount) AS Cases, count(*) rows
FROM RunLog
     INNER JOIN Lot on Lot.runid=RunLog.runid
     INNER JOIN PalletItem ON PalletItem.LotNumber = Lot.ID 
     AND palletitem.palletid=runlog.palletid 
   WHERE RunLog.ActionDate>='2019-06-10 16:52:00'
   AND RunLog.ActionDate<='2019-06-10 19:02:00'
--GROUP BY RunLog.RunID
```

To see how the joins are introducing duplicates into the result before you `Sum` the casecount values.

Comment: Thanks, But I know the problem comes from PalletItem, it is counting that incorrectly, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Why are you joining the other tables if you don't want to sum the casecount for every combination of (RunLog,Lot,PalletItem)?

Comment: This is to provide a production report. Runlog has pallet records for the run. but it has no lot on Runlog. so to provide a lot for the pallet. it is necessary to to the joins. but I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Just saw my mistake on the Join